# Laravel 9 - Install Breeze

Tags: laravel-9

I have created a Fresh Laravel-9 Project, created a database in admin-sql and updated the .env file. After this, I ran following commands:

```
composer require laravel/breeze --dev
php artisan breeze:install
php artisan migrate
npm install
npm run dev
```

I then ran Laravel and registered a user. I then closed my project and closed all command prompt windows. Next time I ran my project and trid to login and got the following error

> Did you forget to run npm install && npm run dev?".

I then ran `npm run dev` and a server started at 127.0.0.1 and then I was able to login.

My question is, everytime I open my project, do I have to run an additional server at 127.0.0.1 using `npm run dev` in addition to `php artisan serve` or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When I used Laravel 9 for the first time, I had the same doubt.
It seems you do need to run it everytime.
But if you do not want to build your files again then you may use the build command

> npm run build